# order of dihedral

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am learning abstract algebra, and I don't quite understand the order of the symmetry of dihedral. When you look at a squares, I agree that there will be 8 symmetry. But all the operations have cycle decomposition of 2 or 4, meaning that it comes back to its original state within 4 repeats. Then how come it has an order of 8? Also, what is the relationship between number of elements(also called order) and the order I am talking about here?

Comment: The order of a group is its size or cardinality. The order of an element $x$ is the least $n$ such that $x^n=e$ (can be $\infty$). The order of a group doesn't have to be the order of any of its elements.

Comment: To answer your last question, the order of an element is so-called because it can be thought of as the order of the cyclic subgroup the element generates.

Comment: Why do you agree there are eight symmetries if you don't know why there are eight symmetries (since you ask "how come it has an order of 8")? Also, why preface "back to its original state within 4 repeats" with the word "But"? What are you suggesting with the word "But" here, explicitly?

Comment: Also, "cycle decomposition" already has a technical meaning for permutation group theory.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are observing demonstrates an important fact about the dihedral groups unnder the standard presentation- that is, they are not cyclic. There is no element $a$ of the dihedral group such that, given an element $b$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $a^n=b$. One cannot in general compose rotations to yield reflections, or vice-versa. 
It is possible that you are confusing two different ideas of order- one being the order of a group, the other being the order of an element of the group. While it is true that one element of a dihedral group may have order 2, and another may have order 4, there is no implication regarding the order of the group as a whole, which represents merely its cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

The number of times it takes applying a symmetry to get back to the original state will be a divisor of the total number of symmetries. But the total number of symmetries can be strictly larger than the number of applications it takes to make any particular symmetry the trivial transformation, as you've observed.

Let's speak in abstract terms. Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$ a particular element. The **order of the element** $g$ is the smallest positive natural $n$ such that $g^n=e$, or infinity if that's impossible, and the **order of the group** $G$ is the total number of elements it has, i.e. its cardinality. Another way of interpreting the order of an element $g$ is as the order of the cyclic group it generates,

$$\langle g\rangle=\{\cdots,g^{-2},g^{-1},e,g^1,g^2,\cdots\}.$$

Lagrange's theorem says if $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$; in particular this means the order of $\langle g\rangle$ - i.e. the order of the element $g$ - divides the order of $G$, but this doesn't necessarily mean there exists any element in $G$ with the same order as $G$ itself. The only time there exists an element whose order equals the size of a finite group, is if the group is cyclic. Dihedral groups are not cyclic, so there is no element of order $8$ in your dihedral group.

In a group $G$ there can be a number $n$ such that $g^n=e$ for all $g\in G$ which is strictly smaller than the size of $G$. The smallest is called the **exponent of the group** $G$, and it is lcm (lowest common multiple) of the orders of all elements of $G$.